# How to avoid ggplot error: "Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (84): x, y"?

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

Here is the code I am trying to run and it is giving me the above mentioned error:

```
dt %>% filter(brand=="volkswagen") %>% 
  filter(Agecat!="NA") %>% 
  group_by(model,Agecat) %>% 
  summarise(Totaldays2close=sum(Days2close)) %>% 
 ## spread(Agecat,Totaldays2close) %>% 
 ## write_csv("Export.csv")


ggplot()+
    geom_col(mapping = aes(x=Agecat,y=Days2close))
```

Where Agecat is categorical variable and Days2close is no. of days required to close deal. Can you suggest how to avoid and why this error is coming?

Comment: Difficult to answer without [seeing some or all](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) of `dt`.

Comment: If you're using `summarise` to create `Totaldays2close`, then `Days2close` may no longer be present in the new dataframe, thus your passing ggplot a column that doesn't exist

Comment: Are you sure that `%>%` should be there at the end of your `summarise` function?

Comment: The pipe (`%>%`) ad the end of the `summarise()` passes the resulting data.frame to `ggpot()`, so it's fine. However, as @ConorNeilson points it out, the `summarise()` function does drop columns that are not summarising or grouping column. You should use `mutate()`instead to keep your original data and add your summarising column to all rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to summarise at it drops columns that are not grouping or summarising columns. Mutate allows you to compute a summary statisitc per group while keeping the rest of the data:

```
dt %>% filter(brand=="volkswagen") %>% 
  filter(Agecat!="NA") %>% 
  group_by(model,Agecat) %>% 
  mutate(Totaldays2close=sum(Days2close)) %>% 
ggplot()+
    geom_col(mapping = aes(x=Agecat,y=Days2close))
```

It should work now.

Comment: Thanks Hobo Sheep, it is working now. Conor Neilson your reasoning is also correct, when I dropped summarise line code then also it started working.

Comment: Glad it worked. Could you please accept the answer (tick mark below votes) so people know it's solved. Cheers.